# What tools do you use to write and communicate Product Requirements?

Tags: agile

Many Product Managers use wiki's or bug tracking software like Jira but there must be a better solution. I would love to get your feedback and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use **Word + Balsamiq** mockups (www.balsamiq.com).

If you deliver Web or desktop applications, and the users need help specifying their needs or the desired visual layout, a mockup is fundamental.

Also, Balsamiq uses a lightweight wireframes style that will help your customer to focus on the information, and not in the graphic details (fonts. etc.)

We track the state of each requirement in a version controlled Excel file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm happy with Word.  I don't think it's the tool that matters as much as the process, or how the tool is used.

Answer (score 1):

1. Mockup tool to clarify requirements together with users
2. Word to create "formal" documents

Some mockup tools can get pretty close to producing the "spec" for developers, too. MockupScreens for example (I am developer):
http://MockupScreens.com

EDIT: Oh, and on a big/formal project you might really need a traceability matrix (you can use Excel for that, or some specialized tool like RequisitePro). You know the situation I'm talking about: there are hundreds of "stakeholder request" that need to somehow be mapped onto "functional requirements" to 1) prove that each request is addressed and 2) to do regression checks when something somewhere changes

Answer (score 0):

Since this post is tagged 'agile' and you framed your question as how you should write and communicate product requirements, I'd say the most common tools used are user stories and conversations.

You mention Jira and wikis, so it seems like one thing you're looking for is a requirements repository. Those are great to have, but don't forget that within most agile frameworks those requirements artifacts are merely placeholders for a conversation. That conversation is the primary requirements communication mechanism for most agile teams and no tool or application can completely replace it.